# Is there a Template Haskell / deriving mechanism for Data.Binary (or friends?)

Tags: serialization, haskell, binary-data, deriving

The `Data.Binary` documentation shows writing an instance by hand. Is there a way around this? I saw [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Data_structures#Serialising_data) there is another library, SerTH, which has a (Template Haskell based) deriving mechanism, but the link to it seems broken. Also, if you know other libraries, good performance is critical for us.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: GHC 7.2 supports this natively using default deriving... I wrote the code for it awhile back and it was pretty simple

Answer (score 7):

See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.7.1.0/doc/html/Data-Binary.html#g:3

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

 import Data.Binary
 import GHC.Generics (Generic)

 data Foo = Foo
          deriving (Generic)

 -- GHC will automatically fill out the instance
 instance Binary Foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Neil Mitchells [Derive package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-2.5.5) has a template haskell macro for deriving binary instances.

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked about other libraries:

The [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) data serialisation library has [cereal-derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-derive), which works with the new Generics support in GHC 7.2. This has a compile-time speed advantage over Template Haskell (I tend to avoid TH these days just because it makes compilation even slower) and a run-time speed advantage over datatype-generic methods like SYB and Uniplate.

cereal is very similar to binary, but uses strict ByteStrings; binary hasn't been updated since 2009 and cereal has niceties such as [IEEE-754 float format support](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/latest/doc/html/Data-Serialize-IEEE754.html), so I can't see any reason not to use it over binary if you want deriving.

Comment: cereal-derive is GPL3.  This might be an issue for some use-cases.

Comment: lazy bytestrings are easier for some use cases